# how do i print numbers between i and b without including i

Tags: java

If the first number is 6 and the second one is 16, it prints `6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15;`

I dont want the "6" to be printed, what statement should I add because I don't want to put them in an array, remove the 6 and resend it

```
System.out.println("enter a number : ");
int i = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("enter another number : ");
int b = input.nextInt();

while (i >= 0 && i<b) 
    System.out.println(i++);
```

Comment: how about performing an `i++` before the loop?

Comment: You could use `++i` instead of `i++`. `i++` evaluates as `i` which is then incremented, while `++i` increments `i` and evaluates as the incremented value.

Comment: @Aaron when using ++i if ints are 5,16 it prints out 6,7,8,9....16;

Comment: @f1sh  performing an i++ before the loop worked too , thanks for the help

Comment: ``for (i = a+1; i <= b; i++)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for loop` like so:

```
    System.out.println("enter a number : ");
    int i = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter another number : ");
    int b = input.nextInt();

    for(int j = i+1; j <= b; j++){
        System.out.println(j);
    }
```

When you input `1 16` it produces:

```
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Comment: im a new stackoverflow user , i can accept the answer in 8 minutes